# Using both flip and slide animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys am trying to make a web flash card . that works like this, if I click on the card I want it to flip but if I click on the navigation it should slide to another card(just like a slide show). Please if anyone has a demo or code for this kindly help me

Comment: Did you try anything to do this? If so, please share snippet and the problem you are facing. Does navigation mean next and previous buttons on the card?

Comment: Yes navigation  means next and previous

Answer (score 0):

Take below site as reference and start creating your page and share code if you struck somewhere.

https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: This should at best be a comment, not an answer. Unless you share a snippet yourself on some implementation of the provided link. I know the question is also bad but still.

Comment: The examples on the site uses only flip,what I am looking for is flip and slide together